# Starting my first Django project on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: django, ubuntu

I have been thinking long and hard about making this post and after hours of Google searches I couldn't come up with any good sources so thought I'd ask here.

I am relatively new to coding, started early this year and started a software programming degree so I am super keen to learn. I have managed to make a fully working project that works on shared hosting but doesn't allow me to use latest packages and modules that is why I upgraded to a VPS. But editing my project on cPanel on a shared hosting was alot less scary than what I'm attempting now.

I've recently purchased a VPS to host my first django project I'm building for my father, the project is basically a gallery that allows him to upload a blog and images. I had a standard shared hosting plan which was fine but I couldn't use latest python and django on it.

So what I want to ask is; what is the common practice for starting off with building a project on ubuntu? In my head it was building it on VSCode and just transferring it to ubuntu, linking it to my domain and BAM.

I've found writing the code very tedious and difficult on ubuntu terminal, using cd to go in and out of folders, copy and paste not working etc. so Is writing it on local pc using VSCode acceptable?

How would static files be stored for my father when he uploads his images/blogs, do they store on the VPS or do I need to link something like AWS which is what I really wanted to avoid when getting a VPS.

I would even appreciate just a step by step list of a common procedure for a project as I have described above.

I appreciate anybody and everybody who is willing to give up some time to help me here.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Writing in your IDE locally to deploy to the server later is the common practice. Your VPS obviously can serve static files too, but check out Cloudflare to reduce the load for static resources. Also learn about CI/CD so you can just push to git and have the VPS automagically pull, build and deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this guide here. It is a beginner friendly approach to setup django:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Hi, that tutorial looks great. I use mysql on local machine so would it make sense to use it on u ubuntu or does it not really matter?

Comment: Does not matter, since django is adaptive to RDBMS, be it Postgres, MySQL, sqLite, etc.

Comment: It is recommended to stick to one database choice both in development and in production. So, it is recommended to use same DB both in development and production.

Comment: So in the section on that tutorial  do I just switch out installing postgres with mysql then? Please excuse my lack of knowledge. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes, install mysql, for this follow the tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-django-app-and-connect-it-to-a-database. Then after you have installed and configured the database, return back to the previous tutorial.

Comment: I thought Id give it ago and ask you this question... I'm struggling so much when it comes to the SSH keys, I can never get them to work, always fail authing. I need to get this working especially not github dont allow HTTP clone, Do you know of any step by step guides to do this? I can't seem to find a decent one.